# * Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException' in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
 reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 
'NSBundle    </Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/726F2DC0-0653-4335-   93DD-40AFB9A00CB9/
data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3AD9B7CD-BB77-4676-B72D-D6504468A389/xxxx.app> (loaded)'
with name '1KQ-aR-y8O-view-UPI-Ak-bBq' 
and directory 'Main.storyboardc'' 
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a90ee65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000109b12deb objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a90ed9d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
3   UIKit                               0x0000000107dfa3cf -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 499
4   UIKit                               0x0000000107bd3eea -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 381
5   UIKit                               0x0000000107bd4816 -[UIViewController loadView] + 178
6   UIKit                               0x0000000107bd4b74 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 138
7   UIKit                               0x0000000107bdaf4f -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 120
8   UIKit                               0x0000000107c0ae44 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 1203
9   UIKit                               0x0000000107c1b23f -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 712
10  UIKit                               0x0000000107c1c3af -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 57
11  UIKit                               0x0000000107dc2ff7 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 248
12  UIKit                               0x0000000107af54a3 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 703
13  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c24f59a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
14  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c243e70 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
15  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c243cee _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
16  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c238475 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 277
17  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c265c0a _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 486
18  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c26637c _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92
19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a83a367 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a83a2d7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a82ff2b __CFRunLoopRun + 1147
22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a82f828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
23  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010bd04ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
24  UIKit                               0x0000000107a3e610 UIApplicationMain + 171
25  baajna                              0x000000010785e61f main + 111
26  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010e92e92d start + 1
27  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
 )
 libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I am not getting expected answer in stack overflow ..It asked by others I tried  all things what they said .But could not figure out my problem. Please guys help me to out from the box. Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you provide some code how you create your `UIViewController`? and how you named it in storyboard?

Comment: I used 15 more UIViewController some of them are                   HomeController.h                                                                               ArtisController.h                                                                                    AlbController.h  and also .m file as usual

Comment: Remove the view from story board and add again with references. Sometimes it holds some references in memory...

Comment: write the perticular code where you can found this crashes.May be your file name is mismatch.

Comment: I checked all file name ..All file name  is alright. When i launch my app it works well ..after some view controller visit  it crashed by provided error

Comment: Can you please provide the code related to the above crash?

Comment: I am not getting specific controller where it crashes because it crash  different view controller at differnt time .

Comment: Show me your coding or else send me your coding

Comment: I have worked last 5 days but still not solved the problem. i use all the solution give in stackOverflow. My os is 10.11.6 and Xcode version 7.3.1 I run my previous apps in this version and face same error but these apps is not an error in previous Xcode version or os. Is there any problem in Xcode version or os ?  please give me solution

Comment: my iOS development target is 9.1

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading view from storyboard then you should user storyboardobject.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("StoryboardIdentifier"). as per my knowledge nib should work only on separate XIB

Answer (score 0):

If you loading Nib UIView. Follow the steps below.

Open XCode Target -> Go to the "Build phases" tab -> Click the "Copy bundle resources" section -> Click the add button -> Add the missing Nib file